# Looking for a control for selecting a directory in Windows Mobile (using .NET Compact Framework)

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

Looking for a control for selecting a directory in Windows Mobile (using .NET Compact Framework). I can find an open and save dialog, but nothing for selecting a directory. Ideally, I'd like this to target the 2.0 framework, but I'm flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but maybe you can modify the following [class-library](http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/02/custom-openfiledialog-implementation.html) to suit your needs.

Above class-library is great since you can overcome one of the most annoying shortcomings of the standard OpenFileDialog, namely the limit of not being able to browse the whole file system (it just let you browse My Documents subfolders and Storage cards).

Maybe not the answer you wanted to heat but hey: it might work out with some slight changes to the code.

Good luck.